# Ajax updates on p:poll

Tags: primefaces

On each ajax update on p:poll, a new additional timer is started.
How can i avoid it? After a few ajax updates, my poll is executed multiple times per second.

This code demonstrates it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <f:view>
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
      <h:form id="testForm">
        <p:commandButton value="Click Me" process="@this" update="@all"/>
        <p:poll id="myPoll" widgetVar="myPollWidget" interval="5" onstart="console.log('Poll....');" process="@this"/>        
      </h:form>
    </h:body>
  </f:view>
</html>
```

I know that i can avoid it, by stopping the poll with

```
onclick="if(PrimeFaces.widgets['myPollWidget']){PF('myPollWidget').stop();}"
```

in the commandButton.

But isn´t there an easier, more generic, way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Effectively you introduce this 'problem yourself by using `update="@all`. So the solutions are: not using `update="@all"` is a very good option but only update those components that need updating or use `ajax="false"` on the commandButton  (almost identical to using `update="@all"`)

Comment: @Kukeltje I am using update="@all" because it is an language selector in my real project and i want to update the whole page without reloading and loosing the viewscope.

Comment: Then use either the codi `@ViewAccessScope` or your solution

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces's poll component has attributes like autoStart and stop in type of boolean. So you can bind these attributes to bean variables and change them with commandButton's actionListener.